# facing problem in adding and removing class in ul and li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a app using Jquery I want to add class and remove class conditionally. In code below there is menu and submenu.

If the user clicks `#two` or `#three` (to open submenu), the submenu class is added to the `ul` tag containing `#two` and `#three` and the menu class is removed.

If the user clicks `#three` or `#four` (on `li` tag), the menu class is added to the `ul` tag containing `#three` and `#four` and the submenu class is removed from the `ul` containing `#one` and `#two`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (!$(".left_pannel ul li ul").hasClass('submenu')) {
      alert("test");
      $(".left_pannel ul li").removeClass("iconadd");
    } else {
      $(".left_pannel ul li").addClass("iconadd");
    }
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="left_pannel">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" class="achore">Matches</a>
        <ul id="one" class="submenu" style="display: none;">
          <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Add Matches(m)</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Add Cricket(m)</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#two" class="achore">Quize Master</a>
        <ul id="two" class="submenu" style="display: none;">
          <li><a href="">Add Matches(m)</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Add Cricket(m)</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="#three"><a href="https://www.google.com">Excel Update</a></li>
      <li id="#four"><a href="#">Application version</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're running the code before the elements you're targeting exist. Use `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks I have improved my code , but stuck with same issue

Comment: Please pay attention to your console. With the code shown here, there are many syntax errors. You may want to read and follow some tutorials on jQuery and how it works.

Comment: You need to add a click event handler for the elements: http://api.jquery.com/click

Answer (score 2):

On click button find class that is **subMenu** , If class is there change class that is **iconadd** or not than remove **iconadd**

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
      $(".left_pannel ul li ul").on("click",function()
      {
        if ($(this).hasClass('submenu')) 
        {      
          $(".left_pannel ul li").addClass("iconadd");
        } 
        else 
        {
          $(".left_pannel ul li").removeClass("iconadd");
        }
      });
    });
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".left_pannel ul li ul").click(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('submenu')) {      
          $(".left_pannel ul li").addClass("iconadd");
        } else {
          $(".left_pannel ul li").removeClass("iconadd");
        }
      });
    });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="left_pannel">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" class="achore">Matches</a>
        <ul id="one" class="submenu" style="display: none;">
          <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Add Matches(m)</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Add Cricket(m)</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#two" class="achore">Quize Master</a>
        <ul id="two" class="submenu" style="display: none;">
          <li><a href="">Add Matches(m)</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Add Cricket(m)</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="#three"><a href="https://www.google.com">Excel Update</a></li>
      <li id="#four"><a href="#">Application version</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

try this code